# Does the number of active visible HWNDs in Windows 7 (or up) affect performance notably?

Tags: c++, c, windows, win32gui

The question is vague admittedly but I'm trying to avoid going down a design rabbit hole. I'd heard anecdotally that creating hundreds of buttons and other controls in an application would be less performant than writing my own windowless controls and handling the mouse click/move/tracking/capture logic my self.

I'll just say my preference is to use HWND based controls because I don't have to reinvent the wheel but not if the application will become unusable.

Comment: Your question seems to hinge on your definition of "notably".  But of course, a custom windowing system **can be** more performant than a general-purpose one.  Why not run a test with hundreds of controls?

Comment: I have apps with 100+ Window controls.  Empirically, it's not a problem.  The GUI system on Windows as designed to work like that.  If it worries you, try it.  Use your form designer to copy/paste panels-full of buttons etc. to make a really big, complex form and see what happens when you run the app.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience with a very HWND-heavy application I don't think you will encounter significant general performance problems.

You will, however, need to make sure you're not exceeding the per-process and per-session handle limits ([which default to 10,000 for a process and 32,768 for the session](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx)) if you are going crazy with creating O/S windows.

At some point, you will simply be unable to create new handles (and therefore unable to create new window objects), your application will start acting in bizarre ways, and it's downhill from there.

You can also run low on desktop heap when you create tons of O/S handles, and this can cause other instability issues.  For these reasons it's best to design in such a way that you stay well under the limits for any conceivable use case.

Comment: When you say "very HWND-heavy" are we talking about hundreds of simultaneously visible windows?

Comment: In our case it was hundreds of simultaneously-visible windows, thousands of HWNDs overall (many of them were hidden at any given time).  I think we maxed out at 12,000, which meant that we had to push out the system defaults to allow a single process to create more than 10,000 handles.

Comment: 'hundreds of simultaneously-visible windows' - you mean 'Access Violation' messageBoxes?  :)  'ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...ping...'

Comment: @MartinJames LOL, no, although it wouldn't have been outside the realm of possibility...